# Difference between adb shell command

Tags: android

windows 7. When I enter into adb shell in cmd  and enter iwpriv wlan0 driver "efuse read 0x3D" in the shell. It could be run well.
But when I directly enter: adb shell iwpriv wlan0 driver "efuse read 0x3D", 
the value in the phone could not be read and Help menu shows.

---

right code:

```
adb shell

iwpriv wlan0 driver "efuse read 0x3D"
```

wrong code:

```
adb shell iwpriv wlan0 driver "efuse read 0x3D"
```

---

Ouput for right code:

```
wlan0        driver:Read success  0x3D = 0x01
```

Output for wrong code:

```
wlan0        driver:

Help Menu:

 Read:

 write:

 Free blocks:
```

---

I do not know why there exists such a difference between using "adb shell + command" (wrong code)  and enter command after entering into adb shell in cmd (right command).
I have tried other command using "adb shell + command" and it works well. How to make the iwpriv wlan0 driver "efuse read 0x3D"  being run successfully using adb shell iwpriv wlan0 driver "efuse read 0x3D"?

Comment: You mentioned using python to execute the command. Can you show us the python code? If you use a form of process opening you could try the following format: `executable name = adb, args = [shell, "iwpriv wlan0...."]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple ,

when you type ,

```
adb shell iwpriv wlan0 driver "efuse read 0x3D"
```

you're supplying `iwpriv wlan0 driver "efuse read 0x3D"`as and argument to shell which shell does not understand.

when you type, `adb shell`

you will enter into shell after that when you type `iwpriv wlan0 driver "efuse read 0x3D"`

shell consider it as a command and executes it.

If you want to execute a adb shell command from python use communicate ,

```
procId = subprocess.Popen('adb shell', stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
out, err=procId.communicate('command1\ncommand2\nexit\n')
```

`out`-output
`err` - error

Comment: But how to let the shell understand the command in adb shell iwpriv wlan0 driver "efuse read 0x3D"?  I use python to auto run the code so I could only use adb shell + command.

Comment: It worked，but I did not get any output in output = procId.communicate('command1\ncommand2\nexit\n'), the output is none.